# Repair corrupted Jupyter notebook / load previous version?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I had a hardware crash while running a Jupyter notebook. After repairing the system and trying to restart the notebook, I got the following error message:

Error loading notebook
Unreadable Notebook: D:\Eddy\Documents\1604 Udacity\1612 Self-driving car Nanodegree\P4\P4 Eduard van Kleef.ipynb NotJSONError("Notebook does not appear to be JSON: ''...",)

Does anyone know of a way to revert to any of Jupyter's previous 'checkpoints'? Or of a way to at least partially restore a JSON?

Comment: JSON is just text. OPen it up and have a look

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
jupyter nbconvert filename.ipynb --clear-output
```

It worked for me since it has corrupted because of Plotly behavior with some big data.

Answer (score 6):

If you are lucky then the ipynb file is corrupted but still there. In that case you can try opening it in a text file and copying the contents to a new notebook. But check the size of the file. If it is zero bytes, then there is nothing there!

This actually happened to me when my server ran out of memory and somehow the notebook got completely erased. Totally sucks.

Comment: Don't know why this got a downvote, as this is sometimes the only thing you can do. +1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

in your file directory that contains your ipynb file there is a folder called '.ipynb_checkpoints'. this folder does not show in the jupyter application so find it through windows explorer.
inside there's will be a file called urfilenamehere-checkpoint.ipynb
copy paste it to your file directory and open through the jupyter application it should probably work.

if your corrupted file is 0B, you definitely have to rely on the checkpoints.

do not create a new notebook with the same name it will overwrite the checkpoint.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are able to access the ipynb, you can checking where the issue is.
Since ipynb files are written in json format, you can check its syntax by running this statements in a new notebook cell:

```py
    import json
    
    with open("your_corrupted_notebook.ipynb") as pynb:
        try:
            report = json.load(pynb)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
```

After that, if you are able to download the corrupted file, you can open it in a regular text editor and fix the error you got when parsing the json.

Answer (score 0):

My main Jupyter .ipynb file and .checkpoint one were completed corrupted. What worked was to go on .ipynb file location on s3, click on `show versions` and find the correct version.